# Opt into a rust trait using an existing function

Tags: rust, traits, implementation

Is there a way to opt into a trait using an existing fn, rather than providing one in the impl block? I.e. if I have a struct with a function:

```
struct Thing(u32);

impl Thing {
    fn get_value_plus_one(&self) -> u32 {
        return self.0 + 1;
    }
}
```

and then I have a trait with a matching function

```
trait PlusOne {
    fn get_value_plus_one(&self) -> u32;
}
```

is there a clean way to get `Thing` to conform to the `PlusOne` trait using the existing `get_value_plus_one` function? This gives a compiler error:

```
impl PlusOne for Thing {} // !! missing `get_value_plus_one` in implementation
```

I know that I could rename Thing.get_value_plus_one to something else (`get_value_plus_one_u32`) and then provide an implementation like this:

```
impl PlusOne for Thing {
    fn get_value_plus_one(&self) -> u32 {
        return self.get_value_plus_one_u32();
    }
}
```

but that introduces a nested fn call. Is it possible to do this without nesting?

Comment: You could annotate the trait method with #`[inline(always)]` to mostly guarantee that the extra call will be eliminated.

Comment: What's the problem with the nested call ? Why don't you implement it in the trait impl (without implementing it for the struct) ? The trait & the struct functions are 2 distinct & independent functions. It does not matter if they have the same name.

Comment: @SvetlinZarev I'm working on an embedded mcu, so pretty concerned about wasting a stack frame. Also new to rust so wanting to learn the best way to express things.

Comment: If you control the struct, why do the method implementation in a standalone impl instead of the trait impl?

Comment: @dominicm00. I ran into this situation when I had a generic struct, but only wanted to implement the trait for some of the specializations